# Scale image with page that's larger than the page in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, scaling

I have an image that I want to resize when the width of the page/screen changes.

This code almost does what I want:

```
.section
{
    position:relative;
    min-width:600px;
    max-width:1200px;
    height:auto;

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image
{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;

    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

<div class="section">
    <img src="long_img.jpg" class="image"/>
</div>
```

The problem is, the image is 2560px wide, and the section is only 1200px. The image gets squashed horizontally to fit, which scales the height down. But, when the page is at it's max width(1200) I want the image to be at full height(400). So I need the image to hang over the edge, but still automatically resize.

The reason I don't just crop the image is because I want to scroll it with a css animation.

I've tried `.image{ margin-right:-1360; }` but it had no effect.

Comment: I don't understand "i need the image to hang over the edge". Can you explain that more?

Comment: The image is 2x as wide as the max-width of the page/div, so for the portion of the image that is visible in the browser window to be at 100%, the image has to hang over the edge of the window.

Comment: So you want the left half of the image to show and scale that half depending on the div's size?? Then animate the image to show the right half of the image?

Comment: Yes. I actually found a bit of a hack that works, which is to do this: .image { width:213.333%; } - but of course, this requires me to manually calculate the %%, and I haven't tried animating that yet..

Comment: Sounds a lot like the solution I came up with (I used :hover instead of animating by the way): http://jsfiddle.net/jjd9rwaf/

Comment: yeah... may be what I get stuck doing ;/

Comment: With animation (on hover): http://jsfiddle.net/jjd9rwaf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query after the css that you have there. This will remove the `100%` declaration and let the image be it's natural size.

```
@media(min-width:1200px) {
    .section img {
        width: auto;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Also, take away the `overflow:hidden` from the containing div.

[See this fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/ew5028kn/).

Comment: all this seems to do is snap the image down to fitting width-wise as soon as the window is shrunk under 1200px

Comment: That's not what you want? What different behavior do you want?

Comment: Example: http://picpaste.com/example-ImqPP0m2.jpg - image hangs over, but still resizes with page